# What is the complexity of this program

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have solved a question on HackerEarth.
The question is

Phineas is Building a castle in his backyard to impress Isabella ( strange, isn't it? ). He has got everything delivered and ready. Even the ground floor has been finished. Now is time to make the upper part. This is where the things become interesting. As Ferb is sleeping in the house after a long day painting the fence (and you folks helped him, didn't ya!), Phineas has to do all the work himself. He is good at this, and all he wants you to do is operate the mini crane to lift the stones. Stones for the wall has been cut and ready waiting for you to lift them up.

Now we don't have Ferb to operate the mini crane, in which he is an expert, we got to do the job as quick as possible. We are given the maximum lifting capacity of the crane, and the weight of each stone. Since it's a mini crane, we cannot place more then 2 stones (of any possible size) at a time, or it will disturb the balance of the crane. we need to find out in how many turns we can deliver the stones to Phineas, who is building the castle.

INPUT: First line of input gives T, the number of test cases. For each test case, first line gives M, the maximum lifting capacity of the crane. first integer N of next line of each test case gives the number of stones, followed by N numbers, specifying the weight of individual stone X.

OUTPUT: For each test case, print the minimum number of turns the crane is operated for all stones to be lifted.

CONSTRAINTS:

```
1 <= T <= 50
1 <= M <= 1000
1 <= N <= 1000
```

Sample Input

```
1
50
3 28 22 48
```

Sample Output

```
2
```

Explanation
In first turn, 28 and 22 will be lifted together. In second turn 48 will be lifted.
Discard the stones with weight > max capacity of crane.

Now I have solved this question and I my source code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(void) {
    int T = 0;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--) {
        int i = 0,M = 0, N = 0,max = 0, res = 0, index = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
        vector<int> v1;
        scanf("%d",&M);
        scanf("%d",&N);
        for(i = 0; i < N ;++i) {
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            if(temp <= M)
                v1.push_back(temp);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < v1.size() ; ++i) {
            max = 0;
            index = 0;
            if(v1[i] != -1) {
                for(j = i + 1; j < v1.size(); ++j) {
                    if(v1[j] != -1) {
                        temp = v1[i] + v1[j];
                        if(temp > max && temp <= M) {
                            max = temp;
                            index = j;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++res;
                v1[i] = -1;
                v1[index] = -1;
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",res);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Now here are my question

1. I want to know the average case time complexity of this code. Also I think worst case complexity of this code would be O(N^2).
2. This is a brute force approach or dynamic programming approach?
3. Is there any better approach then this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belons on code review

Comment: @Walter I don't think you get the point of this kind of problem. This is a OI/ACM type competition question, not a production environment problem. OP simply wanted a better solution and an comments on his own attempt to improve.

Comment: @miushock Then it belongs to [codereview.se]

Comment: @sashoalm it's partially about the code itself and mostly about how to approach this competition programming question. If this belongs to code review, then what are the SO tags like algorithm and dynamic programming are for?

Comment: The "Is there any better approach" question is definitely Code Review territory, but the explain-what-I-wrote part is less so. The existing answer isn't exactly a code review, so the question is no longer a candidate for migration. geeksoul is welcome to cross-post it on Code Review — it's fine as long as you declare the cross-post in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simplified version of [Knapsack Prolblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

While the Knapsack problem is a typical dynamic programming question, this simplified question does not require dynamic Programming. Complexity of your solution is indeed O(n^2), the approach is more suitable described as [Greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) As you tried to find a optimal pair for each stone, if there exist. The complexity can be further reduced to O(nlgn) if you sort the stones first and work on a sorted vector.

Comment: While everyone is fighting for this question is about is off topic, I have one more question. Can above problem implemented with DP or not? (YES or NO ) I don't know why some people are commenting that this question is off-topic? I have not said that review my code and give me ratings? I have just asked for complexity of my code? I respect your views and if some of you agree then I will delete this question but I think this one question can be useful for other guys too who are learning DP and still confuse about there code belongs to DP or not? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also one of the above 3 does belongs to code - review but 2 of them does not and 2 > 1 so I posted here. Also posting same question on another site (code-review stackoverflow) is just simply a wastage of resources and time.

Comment: @geeksoul I can't quite grasp how do you understand DP, but neither the question requires or your code reflect a choice on computed optimal substructure, so I wouldn't say it's a DP question. I'd suggest you read through the knapsack problem wiki and try to implement it yourself, you shall no longer need to ask people this question after that